# Iota dollar balance not displayed

Tags: wallet

I have not accessed my IOTA 2.5.7 light wallet in quite a few months, however I was finally able to get my full balance after a few attaches. I downloaded the Trinity Wallet (with Ledger) and transferred a few over to it from the light wallet. The amount shows up on Trinity but there is no dollar value. Also, I attempted to transfer a few back to the light wallet as a test using the ledger but get the message about NOT ENOUGH FUNDS to transfer, even when I attempt to send 1 Iota. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Marcus, they have changed the API calls from IOTA to MIOTA. It's a known bug that will be fixed in the next update.
"Will be fixed in next version. Just an bug in the API for fetching chart information."

See discussion on Discord on the Trinity-Discussion channel.

Comment: Ok, although I am definitely NOT tech-savvy, what I am getting from your gracious response is that it is safe to transfer the rest of my (M)IOTA from the 2.5.7. wallet over to my newly downloaded Trinity Wallet (with Ledger) and once the Update (bug) is fixed, my actual dollar value will show up as well as the ability to transfer back out to say an Exchange if I wanted to sell a few.
p.s. even though the (M)IOTA shows up in the Trinity Wallet, my balance on the 2.5.7. still has not gone down...?!

Comment: Yes, the IOTA amount you see in your Trinity wallet is what you are interested in. In the next version of the wallet you should see the dollar amount as well.
Disclaimer: I'm not a Trinity wallet developer. I got the answer from Discord in the Trinity-Discussion channel.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Appreciate the responses.